# docker-compose up with multiple yml confs does not start off

Tags: docker, docker-compose

This is the tree structure of my project:

```
.
├── backend-codebase
│   ├── app.js
│   ├── bin
│   │   └── www
│   ├── config.js
│   ├── db
│   │   ├── index.js
│   │   ├── repos
│   │   │   └── todos.js
│   │   └── sql
│   │       ├── index.js
│   │       └── todos
│   ├── dev
│   │   └── postgres
│   ├── index.js
│   ├── package.json
│   ├── public
│   │   ├── images
│   │   ├── javascripts
│   │   └── stylesheets
│   │       └── style.css
│   ├── routes
│   │   ├── api.js
│   │   ├── index.js
│   │   └── users.js
│   ├── scripts
│   │   ├── applyFixtures.js
│   │   ├── dev_entrypoint.sh
│   │   ├── fixtures.json
│   │   └── psql_dump.sql
│   ├── views
│   │   ├── api.ejs
│   │   ├── db.ejs
│   └── yarn.lock
├── dev
│   ├── Dockerfile-node
│   ├── Dockerfile-postgres
│   ├── development.sh
│   ├── docker-compose-common.yml
│   ├── docker-compose-dev.yml
│   └── postgres
│       ├── 12-12-2016_16_58_59.dump
...
```

I use `docker-compose` in order to create three containers and orcherstrate everything:
- a node server
- a postgres DB 
- a data container for the DB

plus, I created two (and a third one is missing) yaml files under `/dev/docker-compose-*.yml`. `docker-compose-dev` extends the common one and should build the images as well as run all the images.

In order to start off everything I tried to launch the following:

```
$ docker-compose up --file dev/docker-compose-common.yml --file dev/docker-compose-dev.yml
```

But what I get is this output:

```
Builds, (re)creates, starts, and attaches to containers for a service.

Unless they are already running, this command also starts any linked services.

The `docker-compose up` command aggregates the output of each container. When
the command exits, all cont
```

I really don't understand what I'm doing wrong

Answer (score 0):

Silly, silly me. 
It was simply the order between the arguments and the command upside-down.

Plus, I can remove the first `--file` argument, since it is referenced by using the `extends` yaml key.

```
docker-compose -f dev/docker-compose-dev.yml up
```